# Magento2.2.5 show original price when configurable product is part of catalog price rule

Tags: magento2, special-price

I have a catalog price rule that setup so I can do a x% off site wide sale. 
Now when i view any category my simple products show the original price crossed out and then show the new discounted price next to it.

However configurable products are showing only the discount price and not the original price? All of the simple products which are inside the configurable product have the same price.

What file do I need to edit and how so that the configurable products will show the original price?

I saw one post about editing

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

However I don't want to edit a core magento file for obvious reasons.

Suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy this file `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml` into your `theme/module` and remove the following condition,

`!$block->isProductList() &&` on line 22:

Original Code:

```
 <?php if (!$block->isProductList() && $block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can anyone give me the exact location where to create the duplicate file of final_price.phtml as I'm unable to find the exact path/ location.

Comment: vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\view\base\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml